# Flutter background task

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, dart, flutter-engine

I'm trying to run a task in backgroung (do not respond with an existing plug-in),
but on the first run I get this error "-32601 received from application: Method not found"

step by step

I have a method that sends, via `MethodChannel`, to the native a handle

```dart
class Backgroundtask {
  static const MethodChannel _channel = const MethodChannel('backgroundtask');

  static Future<bool> periodic({@required Function callback}) async {
    assert(callback != null, 'task cannot be null');

    CallbackHandle handle = PluginUtilities.getCallbackHandle(callback);
    if (handle == null) {
      return false;
    }

    final bool result = await _channel.invokeMethod(
      'periodic',
      <dynamic>[
        handle.toRawHandle(),
      ],
    );
    return result ?? false;
  }
}
```

on the other side, I start a WorkerManager, passing the `handle` as a `Data`.

```kotlin
    override fun onMethodCall(call: MethodCall, result: MethodChannel.Result) {
           [...]
            val data = Data.Builder()
            data.putLong("handle", handle)

            val constrains = Constraints.Builder()
                    .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
                    .build()

            val pWorkRequest = PeriodicWorkRequest
                    .Builder(CustomWorker::class.java, 15, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                    .setInputData(data.build())
                    .setConstraints(constrains)
                    .build()

            WorkManager.getInstance(context).enqueue(pWorkRequest)
            [...]
    }
```

My androidx.work.Worker.doWork()

```kotlin
        [...]
        Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post {
            Log.d("periodic", "background service start")

            val handle = inputData.getLong("handle", 0)
            val flutterEngine = FlutterEngine(context)
            val flutterCallback = FlutterCallbackInformation.lookupCallbackInformation(handle)
            if (flutterCallback.callbackName == null) {
                Log.e("periodic", "callback not found")
                return
            }

            val assets = context.assets
            val bundle = FlutterMain.findAppBundlePath()
            val executor = flutterEngine.dartExecutor
            val dartCallback = DartExecutor.DartCallback(assets, bundle, flutterCallback)

            executor.executeDartCallback(dartCallback)
            Log.d("periodic", "background service end")
        }
        [...]
```

my error occurs after the callback is executed, regardless of what it does.
I think it must be something stupid that I'm not seeing, but my head is broken.

Thank you very much in advance.

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPYso.png)

Comment: flutter clean/flutter upgrade has already been used

Comment: Have you tried ```flutter_isolates``` package? It can help you in executing Method Channel calls in background.

Comment: sorry, i didn't understand, could you give me an idea of ​​how i would implement periodic execution.

Comment: I am sorry I can't provide an example but there's this plugin for audio service in flutter, it uses background execution of dart using flutter_isolates.  you can check this plugin's source code at https://github.com/ryanheise/audio_service

Comment: have you set callback function to static which is being passed in periodic method at dart side